# Open a file from selected text in Vim

Tags: vim

For example, if I have something like this:

```
#include "filename.h"
```

When I select `filename.h` I want to use it as the input for opening the file named `filename.h` in a split.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe you want a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. Press these keys with the cursor over the filename.

Comment: Thanks Rene.  Is there a way to do it using a command?  Using ctrl feels too much like emacs ;)

Comment: I meant to say a : command. Also Ctrl+w Ctrl+f opens it in horizontal split...do you know if there's a way to open in vertical split?  Maybe I should just create a new set of questions :)

Comment: I don't know if a horizontal split is possible. I got used to ctrl in vim, but you might want to consider creating a map in order not to use the controls.

Comment: @user97965 A bit off topic maybe, but you could consider remapping your caps-lock key to ctrl. I find it very convenient, and it's more like the old console Vi was developed on.

Comment: @Chiel92 - or there is another ctrl on the other side of the keyboard

Answer (score 23):

Place your cursor on the file name and press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in normal mode.

```
:help gf
```

You might want to tweak the `'path'` option for a list of directories where the file can be found.

```
:help 'path'
```

Comment: Thanks kemp.  This also works but opens it in the current window.  I prefer to open it in a (horizontal/vertical) split.

Answer (score 8):

If you want this in a vertical split, and as a command, you can run `:vertical wincmd f` with your cursor over the word.

You can shorten this to `:vert winc f` or even `nnoremap gf :vert winc f<cr>` if you so choose.